# Terminate ssl but only for a specific domain in Squid

Tags: proxy, squid

I'd like Squid server to act as an ssl terminator but only for a specific website I own say http://www.example.com. All other request will be via http, no need for SSL termination.

I chatted to the folks @ apache traffic server in freenode, they said ATS can do this. What are the things I need so I can do this in squid?

The reason I need this setup is to be able to cache assets.

Comment: Don't abuse squid as a reverse proxy. Use a proper caching reverse proxy such as nginx, Varnish, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think squid is already quite used to being abused that way. True, it was originally meant as a forward proxy, but there's been a lot of water under the bridge since.

Comment: Just saw this - https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples#Reverse_Proxy_.28Acceleration.29